# Thanks & Thank you followed by a comma or a period as a complimentary closing?

Tags: punctuation

If we use the words "Thanks" or "Thank you" (on a line by itself) at the end of a correspondence -- in the absence of a complimentary closing (such as "Sincerely,") -- do we follow "Thanks" and "Thank you" with a comma or a period?

Example:

Hi Joe,

Body of text ...

Thank you,

Mike

---

Example 2:

Hi Joe,

Body of text ...

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: The answer given below adequately addresses my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a non-native speaker, for my English exams I was taught that in terms of punctuation any letter should be closed in the following fashion:

```
Appropriate closing,
Name
```

Note the comma after the "Appropriate closing" and *no* fullstop after "Name".
So, as far as I can tell, in your case you have written it correctly. A couple of examples for Appropritate closing [are here](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/letterwritingtips/a/letter-closings-list.htm)